# How can I dualboot Ubuntu 17.04 with Lubuntu (to extend battery life)?

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, battery

I know this is not exactly considered a smart move by tech-savvy people like you guys, but I travel a lot and I noticed that using Lubuntu's lightweight environnement helped with battery life. A lot. And sometimes all I need is a word processor, nothing else. I tried installing LXDE desktop but ended up with a very messy desktop...(I'm not an expert).
My dream configuration would include the option to choose between OSs at startup and a shared partition.

Comment: You said your dream configuration would, "include the option to choose between OSs at startup..." So have you installed Ubuntu yet? From that statement it sounds like you haven't, but an earlier sentence you said was, "I tried installing LXDE desktop..." which sounds like you have installed Ubuntu and you're trying to install it on there, or do you mean you were installing it on Lubuntu? Can you please clarify a little?

Comment: You're right, @Erik, I forgot to mention that I already have Ubuntu 17.04 running. I tried installing the LXDE desktop on top of my Ubuntu install.

Comment: Okay, great. So at the moment you can switch between Ubuntu and Lubuntu when you first boot up?

Comment: @Erik Not yet, I only have Ubuntu installed. But I'm going to give a dual-boot a try.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need a separate install with shared partitions and whatnot. 
If you have already installed Ubuntu, what you would need is to install [lubuntu-core](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/lubuntu-core) and because many dependencies are shared with Ubuntu's regular DE, this won't install a lot of extra packages, just the core Lubuntu packages, like `pcmanfm` (actually, this is the only noticeable addition). From a terminal you would type in:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-core
```

Otherwise, there are plenty guides out there and even answers on this site that show you how to install Ubuntu alongside another system, for example, see [How can I install Ubuntu 'alongside' Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75279/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-lubuntu)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Samuel Santana. Does installing lubuntu-core mean I'll have the option at startup or at login to choose between OSs?
Also, I read the thread you mentioned, but it's kind of old so I wasn't sure if it was still relevant (still Lubuntu 11.10).

Comment: You will get an option to switch Desktops at the login screen. You will have Unity, Lubuntu, Lubuntu notebook (or something like that) and Openbox as options. And yeah, the question is still relevant. The important step is partitioning.

Comment: The option to switch desktops is if you go for my suggestion. If you dual boot, then you will have an option to select OS during boot at GRUB's menu. I believe that following my suggestion would be the path of least pain for you.

Comment: I tried installing `lubuntu-core`, but it doesn't exactly do the trick. I can live with Lubuntu-flavored splash screens and colors, but I still have the same processes running in the background. Like you said, it's basically Ubuntu with `pcmanfm` but I wanted a "new" and sleek OS.  I really appreciate your help, but I'll have to keep looking (and learning !).
EDIT: just read your previous comment. I think I'll go for the dual-boot option.

Comment: That's all Lubuntu is, Ubuntu with different base packages. Have you considered just installing Lubuntu? Why do you even need Unity?

Comment: My computer came with Ubuntu (in German, God knows why...) preinstalled. I'm not the biggest fan of Unity but I still like the look and feel and the community-based support you can find online. But you're right, maybe I should get rid of Ubuntu and Unity altogether.

Comment: Regarding community support, Lubuntu **is** Ubuntu, well, in reality it's an official Ubuntu flavour, which means we still get to ask questions on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)! Most solutions that apply to standard Ubuntu also apply to Lubuntu, as is or with an occasional fix.