# Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside 16.04?

Tags: dual-boot

I've been using Xenial 16.04 and I'm thinking of installing 14.04 alongside the existing one so that I can do dual boot. Is this possible? And if so, how can I do it? I'm afraid that I might blow off my Xenial because I've never tried dual booting before.. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible,  you can even install 2 same versions of Ubuntu alongside. You can follow the steps here just instead of Ubuntu you have your Xenial.

[How can I install Ubuntu 'alongside' Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75279/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-lubuntu)

(kind of duplicite answer, but the question is specific due to Xenial, the person was not sure if existing guides fit his specific situation)